# How to plot a sphere in matplotlib using cartesian co-ordinates?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, 3d

I want to plot a sphere of unit radius using matplotlib.Most of the examples and documentations do it by using polar co-ordinates,by my approach is to use Cartesian.When i wrote the code by using just the np.sqrt only the upper part was shown,so i defined a function sq only to receive an error message `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def sq(x):
    if x>=0:
        return np.sqrt(x)
    else:
        return -np.sqrt(abs(x))
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
xlist=np.linspace(-1.0,1.0,50)
ylist=np.linspace(-1.0,1.0,50)
r=np.linspace(1.0,1.0,50)
X,Y= np.meshgrid(xlist,ylist)
Z=sq(r**2-X**2-Y**2)
cp=ax.plot_wireframe(X,Y,Z,color="r")
plt.title('The unit sphere')
plt.show()
```

How can i edit the program which will show the lower part also?

Comment: Roughly half of your values are >= 0, the other half is < 0. So if you ask "are my values >= 0?" numpy is confused, because it doesn't know if you want to know if *any* value or *all* values  are meant to be bigger zero. Independent of that the approach will only ever give you a half-sphere, so you would need two wireframe plots anyways, and in that case you shouldn't run into the problem.

Comment: `x` is an array of arrays

Comment: Why not just plot your positive hemisphere twice? `cp2=ax.plot_wireframe(X,Y,-Z,color="r")`

Comment: I should clarify I meant plot 1 being positive and 1 being negative since they use the same x,y grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the other half of the hemisphere you are creating, simply plot the same hemisphere but negative. Your methodology won't work because for a given x,y coordinate you need 2 values (i.e. +/- z). So even if you set the Z values for a given negative X to be negative you will still not achieve a sphere. If you want a smoother plot then you do need to use the polar coordinate calculation to get the correct sphere boundary values.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
xlist=np.linspace(-1.0,1.0,50)
ylist=np.linspace(-1.0,1.0,50)
r=np.linspace(1.0,1.0,50)
X,Y= np.meshgrid(xlist,ylist)

Z=np.sqrt(r**2-X**2-Y**2) #Use np.sqrt like you had before

cp=ax.plot_wireframe(X,Y,Z,color="r")
cp=ax.plot_wireframe(X,Y,-Z,color="r") # Now plot the bottom half


plt.title('2D Contour Plot of The unit sphere')
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Note**

If you want the sphere to look more like a sphere using this approach, you can increase the resolution and increase the `rstride` and `cstride` like so. You could also rotate your axis as well. For example:

```
xlist=np.linspace(-1.0,1.0,10000)
ylist=np.linspace(-1.0,1.0,10000)
X,Y= np.meshgrid(xlist,ylist)
Z=np.sqrt(1**2-X**2-Y**2) #Note your r is redundant, use 1.

ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")

cp=ax.plot_wireframe(X,Y,Z,color="r", rstride=1000, cstride=1000)
cp=ax.plot_wireframe(X,Y,-Z,color="r", rstride=1000, cstride=1000)


plt.title('2D Contour Plot of The unit sphere')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify why its wrong? The invalid values are there by default because of the grid setup. The point X=-1, and Y=-1 should not have a value which would correspond to a radius of sqrt(2)/2 and hence is negative when given r=1. The value is still implicit in the calculation and is why the invalid value is there. Also the sphere looks more and more complete if you increase the resolution of the grid...

Comment: Yes, that aspect is more clearly highlighted if you use `scipy.sqrt` instead of `np.sqrt`

Comment: But OP uses `numpy` :) . Scipy is more accurate in its calculation with complex numbers of course, but in this case a `Nan` is preferable for plotting purposes. Imaginary numbers are not physical in this case.